# How can i add custom tags to my SNS events that gets sent to Datadog Event management

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, datadog

I am trying to add custom tags to SNS messages that are sent to Datadog from an AWS Lambda function written in Python. The Datadog events only have the default tags. How can I add custom tags to the SNS event messages?

```
    message = (
        f"The cost percentage difference for the account {role.split(':')[4]} has exceeded {COST_THRESHOLD}%. Diff: {percentage_diff}%."
    )
    response = sns_client.publish(
        TopicArn=SNS_TOPIC_ARN,
        Message=json.dumps({"default": json.dumps(message)}),
        MessageStructure="json"
    )
    logger.info(f"## SNS Topic notified {SNS_TOPIC_ARN} ")
```

I am trying to send SNS events to datadog based on a comparison, i have an event v2 monitor set up in Datadog that triggers based on these events, but since the events come with the default tags, events meant for different purposes that come from SNS also trigger the monitor which shouldn't happen.